# Facebook like button case

Tags: facebook

everyone..

My problem is I added facebook like button to my dynamically generated php page in my website.  [This is such a page](http://www.lankainstitute.com/1281/Namal%20Sanjeewa/)

But it is not working as I expect. When I liked facebook not display my liked information.

any comments are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `og:url` in your OpenGraph Meta tags in URL encoded form which is wrong.

Your page located at:

```
http://www.lankainstitute.com/1281/Namal%20Sanjeewa/
```

and this is URL you should use in your `og:url` tag instead of:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lankainstitute.com%2F1281%2FNamal%2520Sanjeewa%2F
```

BTW, You should use [Debug tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to discover errors in your OpenGraph data.

Comment: I add this code to create that url dynamically. This is that code <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo urlencode("http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>" />. So what is the wrong with it????

Comment: Don't use `urlencode` and you'll be fine. Result of `urlencode` isn't correct URL but encoded string intended to be passed as URL arguments, you don't need it this time.